# Dúvida sobre "resorteio" de valores iguais

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz um exercício de sorteio utilizando dicionário:

```
from random import randint               
from time import sleep              
from operator import itemgetter

jogo = {'jogador 1': randint(1,6), 'jogador 2': randint(1,6), 'jogador 3': randint(1,6), 'jogador 4': randint(1,6)}                                                                              
ranking = {}                      
print('Valores Sorteados')              
for k,v in jogo.items():                     
    print(f' {k} tirou {v} no dado')                                                    
    sleep(1)

ranking = sorted(jogo.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)             
for k, v in enumerate(ranking):             
    print(f'{k+1}º lugar: {v[0]} com {v[1]}')
```

Contudo, às vezes os jogadores apresentam valores iguais, como é o caso do exemplo abaixo. O jogadores 3 e 2 possuem o mesmo valor (4), mas apenas o jogador 3 se encontra em 2º lugar.

```
1º lugar: jogador 4 com 5              
2º lugar: jogador 3 com 4 <-       
3º lugar: jogador 2 com 4 <-  
4º lugar: jogador 1 com 2
```

Como faço para realizar um novo sorteio **apenas** entre os jogadores com valores iguais para disputarem o 2º e 3 º?

Ex:

```
1º lugar: jogador 4 com 5                                     
2º lugar: jogador 3 com 4  
3º lugar: jogador 2 com 4  
4º lugar: jogador 1 com 2   

2º lugar: jogador 3 com 4  -> RESORTEIO -> jogador 3 com 2                          
3º lugar: jogador 2 com 4  -> RESORTEIO -> jogador 2 com 6                                                 

1º lugar: jogador 4 com 5                                     
2º lugar: jogador 2 com (4 na 1º tentativa, 6 no resorteio)               
3º lugar: jogador 3 com (4 na 1º tentativa, 2 no resorteio)                    
4º lugar: jogador 1 com 2
```

Comment: isso vai dar trabalho, não seria mais fácil gerar os jogadores um a um, e na hora de atribuir o valor aleatório ver se já existe e atribuir outro em seguida?

Answer (score 4):

Até seria possível pedir para o código ficar repetindo os sorteios de todos os jogadores, ou só dos jogadores com mesmo número, mas considere a seguinte abordagem no lugar disso:

- iniciamos uma sequência numérica com os valores possíveis para o jogo:

  ```
  # valores possíveis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  valores = list(range(1, 7))
  ```
- embaralhamos essa sequência:

  ```
  import random
  random.shuffle(valores)
  ```
- definimos o número total de jogadores

  ```
  max_jogadores = 4
  ```
- criamos um dicionário com base nesse parâmetro, pegando sequencialmente os elementos da sequência de valores. **Esse é o ponto-chave**: como a sequência é composta de **elementos únicos** e **está embaralhada**, podemos simplesmente atribuir cada elemento da sequência a cada jogador em ordem, sem nos preocuparmos com repetições.

  ```
  jogo = {f'jogador {i+1}': valores[i] for i in range(max_jogadores)}
  ```

Output (no meu caso, varia a cada execução):

```
{'jogador 1': 3, 'jogador 2': 5, 'jogador 3': 6, 'jogador 4': 2}
```

Um detalhe interessante é que a linha  `jogo = ...` vai causar um `IndexError` caso o número de jogadores seja maior do que os valores disponíveis na sua lista. Pode parecer ruim, mas caso isso acontecesse com a sua ideia original, o código ficaria silenciosamente em um loop infinito ao tentar atribuir valores únicos a um número de jogadores superior ao número de valores possíveis.